# change color for single character in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using ✔ character in NSMutableString. I want to change its color to green. how can I change it. I have applied color attribute for it.

```
[String addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                       value:[UIColor greenColor]
                       range:NSMakeRange(107, 1)];
```

I have tried this solution with the other normal character in string. And its changing its color. but for particular this character its not changing the color. How can I use green color for this character

Comment: Did you mean `NSAttributedString` ?

Comment: yes NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: I just tried changing color for complete string. all other characters color changes but for this , it appears dark gray color

Comment: Indeed the color attribute doesn't seem to work for some characters.

Comment: can you suggest how can try it using UIBezierPath?

Comment: found link where someone has suggested it using UIBezierPath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996362/drawing-a-checkmark-nsstring-with-uikit-doesnt-respect-fill-color

Comment: You could use something like [font-awesome](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome) instead? It's characters can be colored.

Comment: Or use the ✓ character instead. It might be better.

Comment: Thanks for feedback guys.. I solved this task by using inline image. like as 
UIImage *checkImage = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_check.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(16,16)];

    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment.image = checkImage;
    
    NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

Answer (score 0):

var myString1:NSString = "(Active)"

```
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var str = NSString()
    str = "Name"
    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (str as String) + (myString1 as String), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 18.0)!])

    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.grayColor(), range: NSRange(location:str.length, length:myString1.length))


    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14.0)!, range: NSRange(location: str.length,length: myString1.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
do{

    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "✔", options: NSRegularExpression.Options(rawValue: 0))
    let range: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
    regex.enumerateMatches(in: text, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: range) { (resultTxt, flags, stop) in
        if let subStringRange = resultTxt?.range(at:0){
            result.addAttributes([.foregroundColor :color], range: subStringRange)
        }
    }
}
catch {

}
```

Comment: Can you add some comments so it's easier for other users?

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode char of ✔.

Try this and see:

```
NSString *testString = @"I am using \u2713 character in NSMutableString. I want to change its color to green. how can I change it. I have applied color attribute for it.";

NSString *tickmark = @"\u2713";
NSRange tickRange = [testString rangeOfString:tickmark];
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testString];
NSDictionary *tickAttrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor] };
[attributedString addAttributes:tickAttrs range:tickRange];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 120, 200, 400)];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
label.attributedText = attributedString;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Result:

[image]